# Extract an html tag and attribute from NSString

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, regex, parsing

I have a NSString that contains a HTML page. I would to extract a particular tag by id and a particular attribute (of this tag) by name.
I used regular expression as this example:

```
NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *authParameter = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<form id=\"theIdOfForm\"*.*method=\"post\">" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

    if (error == nil) {
        NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:aHtmlFirstResponse options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [aHtmlFirstResponse length])];

        if (match) {
            NSString *formHtmlTag = [aHtmlFirstResponse substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:0]];

}
```

but, how can I extract the attribute by name from this tag?
What is an elegant and efficient way to obtains this?
I would like to avoid importing some HTML parser library.

Comment: NSTextCheckingResult  gives you a range of its match, allowing you to specify a substring to extract pieces from. In some cases you'll want to break it up with additional regex's. I prefer to use RegexKitLite, which makes expression parsing and result extraction quite a bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser

I have used this for one of my project.